# Why default value in mat-select doesn't display?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have component1.ts:

```
selectOptions: [
        {
            value: 'HH:mm',
            label: '24 - hour',
        },
        {
            value: 'hh:mm a',
            label: '12 - hour',
        },
    ];
selected: string = 'SomeValue';
someForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.someForm= new FormGroup({
            value: new FormControl(null)
        })
    }
```

component1.html

```
<form [formGroup]="someForm" class="form__wrapper">
        <mat-form-field class="views__wrapper">
            <mat-select formControlName="value" [(value)]="selected" class="cities__views">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of viewsOptions" [value]="option">{{
                    option.label
                }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

I can switch values, but when i open page, default value doesn't display
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide us a stackblitz with your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove [(value)]="selected" from html and pass value in FormGroup

so:

```js
this.someForm= new FormGroup({
        value: new FormControl('HH:mm')
 })
```

Comment: I tried it, but it also doesn't work :(

Comment: try this one: change [value]="option" to [value]="option.value" in the mat-option.

Comment: because you pass whole object to the value ( i mean [value]="option" ) and you should specify which field is the value. in this case **option.value** is proper field that you should pass.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't display because in your array "selectOptions" the selected value "SomeValue" doesn't exist.

This should work:

TS:

```
selectOptions: [
        {
            value: 'SomeValue',
            label: 'SomeValue',
        },
        {
            value: 'HH:mm',
            label: '24 - hour',
        },
        {
            value: 'hh:mm a',
            label: '12 - hour',
        },
    ];
selected: string = 'SomeValue';
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="someForm" class="form__wrapper">
        <mat-form-field class="views__wrapper">
            <mat-select formControlName="value" [(value)]="selected" class="cities__views">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of selectOptions" [value]="option.value">{{
                    option.label
                }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

Or if you wants a timevalue directly

TS:

```
selectOptions: [
        {
            value: 'HH:mm',
            label: '24 - hour',
        },
        {
            value: 'hh:mm a',
            label: '12 - hour',
        },
    ];
selected: string = 'HH:mm';
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="someForm" class="form__wrapper">
        <mat-form-field class="views__wrapper">
            <mat-select formControlName="value" [(value)]="selected" class="cities__views">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of selectOptions" [value]="option.value">{{
                    option.label
                }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```